# Hilbert space and a form of Cauchy Schwarz inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

This question was asked in an assignment of Functional Analysis. I am self studying this course and having a very hard time doing assignments. Course is online and I study at a really poor university.

> Question: Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Show that if $A_1, ..., A_N,B_1,..., B_N \in L(H)$, then $\| \sum_{i=1}^N A_i B_i \|^2 \leq \| \sum_{i=1}^N A_i A^* \| \times \| \sum_{i=1}^N{B_i}^* B_i\|$.

Attempt: Although I have studied class notes very well, still I have no idea on which result to use. I think you should provide me couple of hints in comments and then I will work on those comments. I am sorry that I have no attempt to show.

I am sorry but I have no other help than this site.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you define what is $L(H)$?

Comment: @PC1 L(H,H) =L(H) and L(H,H) the space of linear continuous linear maps from X to Y endowed with sup norm.

Comment: Try looking at $\sup_{\|x\|=1,\|y\|=1}|\langle Hx|y\rangle|=\|H\|$ for an operator H.

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for Hilbert $C^*$-modules applied to $L(H)$ which becomes an $L(H)$-module in the obvious way. Even if you don't know this, you can just mimique the proof of the usual Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

**EXTENDED COMMENT**

1. It is "Cauchy-Schwarz", not "Cauchy-Schwartz". L.Schwartz was a mathematician but a much more recent one.
2. Clearly, you should try to adapt the proof of the standard Cauchy-Schwarz $(\sum_i a_ib_i)^2 \le \sum a_i^2\sum b_i^2$, where $a_i, b_i$ are real numbers. What happens if you try to do so? Where do you need further ideas?
3. [Personal opinion] "I study at a really poor university". " I don't deserve any answer". "I am sorry etc..." You often use remarks like these. They add nothing at all to your questions while looking seriously unprofessional. I would avoid them.

Comment: @Guiseppe Thanks for all the comments! I will certainly implement upon your advice.

Comment: @Guiseppe I knew I should apply Cauchy Schwartz inequality but I was not able move even a step forward. Can you please help me by writing a complete answer?

Comment: Do you mind elaborating your answer?